# Field of view (FOV) of the Camera - ArcGIS Java runtime SDK

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I'm trying to set the 3D Camera of the SceneView in the Java SDK and I cannot find a "field of view" / "angle of view" member.
I was wondering how the camera's field of view is being set, since I need a way to change it according to the horizontal and vertical field of views.

Comment: which field of view are you talking about ? The IFOV of pixel, the FOV of the optical device (angle) or the extent of the map viewed by the camera ?

Comment: the FOV of the optical device (angle)

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the camera does not work like a real camera but gives you the line of sight that is needed to build the perspective. Instead of manipulating the camera properties, you should manipulate the view properties based on its extent or the zoom of the map. Of course, this needs some manipulations of the variable, knowing that the scale = "extent on map"/"extent in reality" and that AFOV = 2* (tan-1) ("extent in reality"/(2*"distance between camera and object")

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use v100.6, where a SetFieldOfView method was added to the SceneView control (it's not directly on the camera).
The method takes the horizontal FoV, and the vertical is a function of the width/height ratio of the control. There's another overload that allows you to "squish" the vertical ratio as well, if you have some specific camera matching needs.